# Can I use ffmpeg audio filters on encoding?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio, encoding

ffmpeg has a [ton of audiofilters available](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Audio-Filters), and for a current project I need a compressor on the audio mix (not on separate tracks, just at the end during the encoding process).
Is there a way to manipulate the commandline that Blender is using to run ffmpeg, or is this not how it is working? Any tips how I could achieve this would be great. Thanks

Comment: I think that access to ffmpeg commands in Blender is rather limited. Also you couldn't preview the results of any change until after render. I doubt that such a system would be encouraged in Blender.

Comment: I see. I totally understand that no one wants all the options inside Blenders UI, but it would be cool if there was just an empty field where you could add custom commandline flags that should be added to the command. Seems like I need to do a custom build for this :/

Comment: Certainly not a new idea. When they recently reimplemented output codec variables it was decided to dumb them down instead of open them up. I was hopeful

Comment: Wrong decisions so often... I hope I can fix this myself. We probably throw Blender out of the pipeline beofore adding another inbetween renderstep. Damn...

Comment: Why not just use ffmpeg via command line?

Comment: because it would mean an additional step in the process... render from Blender and then encode with ffmpeg